# Write exercises outline to a text file

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files, exercises

I have a document that uses the `exercise` package. And I would like to produce an auxiliary file that contains the outline of the exercises and questions. The file will be processed by an external tool later on.

I would like my auxiliary file to contain one line per exercise and question. The lines for exercises should contain the content of the `title` option, and the lines for the questions should contain the optional tag. Like this.

```
Exercise 1: \textit{(Bonus)} Solving sudokus
Q1: solve
Q2: prog
```

Here's a Minimal Mostly-Working Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{exercise}


\AtBeginDocument{
    \newwrite\exerciseoutline
    \immediate\openout\exerciseoutline=\jobname.exo
}
\AtEndDocument{
    \immediate\closeout\exerciseoutline
}
\let\Questionorig=\Question
\renewcommand\Question[2][]{
    \Questionorig{#2}\immediate\write\exerciseoutline{Q\theQuestion : #1}
}
\renewcommand\AtBeginExercise{
    \immediate\write\exerciseoutline{\ExerciseName \ExerciseHeaderNB : \ExerciseTitle}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}[title=\textit{(Bonus)} Solving sudokus]
    \Question[solve]{Solve a sudoku}
    \Question[prog]{Write a program that solves a sudoku}
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

There are two issues with my example.

First, I didn't find a way to put just a space between the content of `\ExerciseName` and `\ExerciseHeaderNB` in the file.

Second, when the exercise title contains some formatting, like in the example containing `\textit{(Bonus)}`, it fails with the following error:

```
! Argument of \@no@pgbk has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.24 ...e}[title=\textit{(Bonus)} Solving sudokus]
```

I think the most general way of handling this would be to throw the LaTeX formatting commands uninterpreted into the file. But if it's simpler, I'd also accept an answer that simply remove all the LaTeX commands and only write the text part `(Bonus) Solving sudokus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use the LaTeX 2ε-kernel-macros `\@starttoc` and `\addtocontents`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{exercise}

% \AfterLastShipout from atveryend is needed with older
% LaTeX-distributions.
% With up-to-date LaTeX-distributions atveryend is just a
% compatibility-wrapper for using new LaTeX 2e-kernel-
% "infrastructure", doing \AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}.
\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@input\@gobble
  \@starttoc{exo}%
  \endgroup
}%
\@ifdefinable\Questionorig{\let\Questionorig=\Question}%
\makeatother
\renewcommand\Question[2][]{%
    \Questionorig{#2}%
    \addtocontents{exo}{Q\theQuestion : #1}%
}%
\renewcommand\AtBeginExercise{%
    \addtocontents{exo}{\ExerciseName\space\ExerciseHeaderNB : \ExerciseTitle}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}[title=\textit{(Bonus)} Solving sudokus]
    \Question[solve]{Solve a sudoku}
    \Question[prog]{Write a program that solves a sudoku}
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

You get the following .pdf-output:

[image]

You get the following .exo-file:

```latex
Exercise 1: \textit {(Bonus)} Solving sudokus
Q1: solve
Q2: prog
```